# How to replace an observeEvent with a more comprehensive reactive function in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, observers, shiny-reactivity

The code at the bottom of this post works as intended, using `observeEvent(input$choices...)` in the server section. The use of `input$choices` is a simplification for sake of example ease. In the fuller code this excerpt derives from, the equivalent of "choices" is molded by many different inputs (call it a "floating reactive"), and unless I misunderstand `observeEvent()`, it won't be feasible to use `observeEvent()` in the fuller code because I would have to list the myriad inputs that can alter it. So, is there a way to genericize this code where it instantly captures any change to "choices" (again, "choices" is a simplified analogy for my more complex floating reactive) and outputs it to the 2nd row of the table, including added rows?

Also in the below image, I show how "choices" is a always parachuted into the 2nd position of the dataframe in all circumstances (maybe there's a simpler way to do this too):

[image]

Code:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,1,0,1), check.names = FALSE)
rownames(mydata) <- c('Term A','Floating reactive','Term C','Term D') 

ui <- fluidPage(br(),
  useShinyjs(), 
  uiOutput("choices"),br(),
  rHandsontableOutput('hottable'),br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(1,actionButton("addSeries", "Add",width = '70px')),
    column(3,hidden(uiOutput("delSeries2"))) 
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTable <- reactiveVal(mydata)
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable, {uiTable(hot_to_r(input$hottable))})
  
  output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTable(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$choices,{
    tmpTable <- uiTable()
    tmpTable[2,]<- as.numeric(input$choices)
    uiTable(tmpTable)
  })
  
  output$choices <- 
    renderUI({
      selectInput(
        "choices", 
        label = "User selects value to reflect in row 2 of table below:",
        choices = c(1,2,3)
      )
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,1)) 
    newCol[2,] <- as.numeric(input$choices) 
    names(newCol) <- paste("Series", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable)) + 1)
    uiTable(cbind(uiTable(), newCol))
  })
 
  output$delSeries2 <- 
    renderUI(
      selectInput(
        "delSeries3", 
        label = NULL,
        choices = colnames(hot_to_r(input$hottable))
      )
    )

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question I'm afraid, but I'm interested to know why your `mydata` dataframe is apparently transposed - you seem to have a row each for your variable, which you've had to add rownames for.  The typical approach for a data frame is one column per variable, one row per record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get the point here, but you might want to use `observe` instead of `observeEvent` to avoid managing the reactive dependencies (`eventExpr`) yourself:

```
library(rhandsontable)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

mydata <- data.frame('Series 1' = c(1,1,0,1), check.names = FALSE)
rownames(mydata) <- c('Term A','Floating reactive','Term C','Term D') 

ui <- fluidPage(br(),
                useShinyjs(), 
                uiOutput("choices"),br(),
                rHandsontableOutput('hottable'),br(),
                fluidRow(
                  column(1,actionButton("addSeries", "Add",width = '70px')),
                  column(3,hidden(uiOutput("delSeries2"))) 
                )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  uiTable <- reactiveVal(mydata)
  
  observeEvent(input$hottable, {uiTable(hot_to_r(input$hottable))})
  
  output$hottable <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(uiTable(),rowHeaderWidth = 100, useTypes = TRUE)
  })
  
  observe({
    req(input$choices)
    tmpTable <- uiTable()
    tmpTable[2,] <- as.numeric(input$choices)
    uiTable(tmpTable)
  })
  
  output$choices <- 
    renderUI({
      selectInput(
        "choices", 
        label = "User selects value to reflect in row 2 of table below:",
        choices = c(1,2,3)
      )
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$addSeries, {
    newCol <- data.frame(c(1,1,0,1)) 
    newCol[2,] <- as.numeric(input$choices) 
    names(newCol) <- paste("Series", ncol(hot_to_r(input$hottable)) + 1)
    uiTable(cbind(uiTable(), newCol))
  })
  
  output$delSeries2 <- 
    renderUI(
      selectInput(
        "delSeries3", 
        label = NULL,
        choices = colnames(hot_to_r(input$hottable))
      )
    )
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Well, this was difficult for me to verbalize, apologies for the confusing post. Yet you seem to have the ability to read minds and hit the nail on the head again. I'll go with the observe() solution as I move forward.